# Video editor with bubble annotations

Tags: video-editor, annotation

I use the annotations feature of YouTube a lot, but I want to get away from flash and start hosting my videos using html5. So I need to create those bubbles and embed them in the video using an editor. Is there an easy way to do that or a video editor that has such feature?

Comment: Possibly a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

**[Advene](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/advene-annotate-digital-video-exchange-on-the-net.html)**

[image]

Advene Project: http://liris.cnrs.fr/advene/index.html

Comment: Sounds interesting. However, the user needs to load the video and annotations in the application. I need something for web display.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, I would say hard-embedding them on top of your video is way too destructive. YouTube agrees with me; they don't edit the videos you annotate, they just show a deebrie above the video.

And you can do exactly what YouTube does with your HTML video. The difference is *you* need to do it. In short: load a list of annotations (their text, time, duration and position), listen to the playing event of the video, and the pop up divs over the video while it's playing.

There are HTML5 "players" out there (they're more frameworks around the `<video>` tag) but none I know of do this for you. JW Player probably has the most advanced solution but it's still in development and they claim their JS API "will" change before final release. You might need to change things as they do but it's still a base to work from.

http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/HTML5Overview

Comment: I agree with you and this would be a great solution. However, I'm trying to reduce my web sites workload to focus more on the development, so doing such thing manually wouldn't be ideal.