# What Software to Use for Tagging/Annotating/Commenting/Highlighting Video Footage?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, tag, tagging, media-manager

### My Question in a Nutshell

I’m looking for a tool with which I can easily organize/manage the video footage I have recorded. I don’t want to only tag the video clip files themselves, though; I would rather like to **add notes to different positions *in* the videos** so that I can more easily find the highlights of my shots later.

I’m not looking for solutions which change the videos themselves. It’s really just about **adding metadata on the frame level**.

### What I have Found

As far as I can see, [most existing media management tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/29513/137449) only allow to tag on the file level but for videos it would be very helpful to add tags/markers on the timeline (or frame level) of each video.

The only tool that I have found which comes close to what I’m looking for is Advene – suggested in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/14527/137449). Unfortunately, I couldn’t get Advene to display any of my videos.

With Blender I could somehow do what I need, however, it’d be overkill and cumbersome to use for this task.

### What I have in Mind as the Ideal Solution

The ideal tool would be a GUI program like Totem or VLC in which I can easily add notes to the video which is currently being played. A note would either be tied to a single timecode or to a span between two timecodes. Adding a note would be done with a keyboard shortcut which automatically pauses the video and then provides a text field in which a comment can be added.

The tool would store the notes in a text-based format in a somewhat configurable way. That way, notes could easily be searched later across files with the help of existing tools like grep.

Since I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I would somehow want to be able to run the tool there.

Less ideal but still useful: a tool as described above which can only add highlight markers at certain timecodes (i.e., without text notes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Best Solution: Totem

In Totem you can create custom chapters. By choosing “Chapters” from the “View”, you get a sidebar for working with chapters:

[image]

By clicking the “Add New Chapters” button in the sidebar and then using the buttons at the bottom of the sidebar, chapter markers can be added, deleted and saved:

[image]

Saving creates a new file with the same name as the video file (but with a different suffix) right next to the video file. The new file is in the XML-based [Continuous Media Markup Language (CMML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Media_Markup_Language) format, i.e., it can be easily searched with for example `grep`.

Since the CMML format is open, such chapter files can also be created by other tools and loaded into Totem. This might become handy, for example, when [extracting HiLight tags](https://superuser.com/q/881661/216900) from GoPro cameras and converting them to CMML for viewing in Totem.

### Honorable Mention: VLC

VLC has a “Custom Bookmarks” item in the “Playback” menu that can be used for marking positions in videos. These boomarks can be saved into a playlist from where they can also be loaded again.

Unfortunately the feature seems to have been [partly broken for a while now](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/2100).

Comment: I do not see the "chapters" feature anywhere in the Totem that ships with Ubuntu 18.04.  And VLC custom bookmarks go away once the program exits, but a page regarding this points to https://www.vlchelp.com/skipping-and-playing-audio-and-video-portions-in-vlc/ as an alternative.